# Using Tcl_SetChannelOption function when creating TCL C channel

Tags: c, tcl, channel

I want to implement my Tcl_Channel that will communicate between Tcl and C.
I saw that after creating a channel using Tcl_CreateChannel(...) there is use of

```c
Tcl_SetChannelOption(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Channel chan, cons char *optionName, const char *newValue);
```

TCL-C API function , furthermore , I saw that almost always what is passed to this function is the following:

- Argument 1 : NULL
- Argument 2 : ClientData
- Argument 3 : "-translation" or "-buffering"
- Argument 4 : "lf" (in case of -translation) or "none" (in case of
  -buffering)

I tried to search and understand why this parameters are passed to this function and more important, What is the meaning of this flags and values and couldn't find anything.
I need an explanation of why to use this function and how to use it?

Comment: The function is the C API that `fconfigure` sits in front of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

- `-translation` is about how to deal with line ending chars (as they can vary on Windows, Linux and MacOS).
- `-buffering` is about how often to put data to the channel (as it may be costy to do that too often, or may be counter-productive to introduce any delay).

All that options would take an effect for further reads/writes performed on the channel.
So, instead of googling for `Tcl_SetChannelOption`, you have to check mans for the options itself (as that two are not the only options applicable). For instance:
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm